# Отступы между ячейками в таблице

Tags: html

Наиглупейший вопрос: как сделать отступы между ячейками `<td>` и между столбцами `<tr>` в таблице.
+ Еще нужно сделать border-radius для каждой ячейки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так:

```
td, tr {
  display: inline-block;
}
td {
  margin-left: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
tr {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Убираем отступы для первой строки и первого столбца, если надо:

```
td:first-child {
  margin-left: 0px;
}
tr:first-child {
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

Или так:

```
table {
    border-spacing: 5px 5px; /* Горизонтальный отступ, вертикальный отступ */ 
}
```

Comment: если бы оно так просто работало - я бы не спрашивал :3
НЕ РАБОТАЕТ так 3(

Comment: Да, действительно) Исправил и проверил, теперь работает.

Comment: Добавил радмус в первый вариант. Скорее всего, придётся им и пользоваться, если закруглённые углы нужны.